# Чтение URL с помощью лямбда-выражений

Tags: java

Как можно с помощью лямбда-выражений прочитать текстовый документ по ссылке? Т.е. создается объект `URL url = new URL("http://www.nkode.io/assets/programming/countmychars.txt");`
Но как читать содержимое документа с помощью лямбды?

Comment: Эээ... Лямбда — это всего лишь определённая вами функция (ну да, анонимная, но всё равно функция). Ваш вопрос по сути «как прочитать содержимое документа при помощи функций».

Comment: Но ведь лямбдами можно заменить почти любой цикл, разве нет? Т.е. вместо того, чтоб писать
BufferedReader input = ....
while( (line == input.readline()) != null)
можно же наверняка создать лямбду? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Заменить цикл лямбдами? о_О

Comment: Ok. Возможно выразился неправильно(студент еще). С помощью потока Stream =)

Comment: @EvheniiVasylenko вам нужно серьезно прочитать, что такое лямба-выражения))))

Comment: Весь день читал Ричарда Уорбэртона - Лямбда выражения в Java 8. Но так и не понял, как применять Stream для чтения файла.

Comment: Ну допустим есть [`bufferedReader.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--]) и [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), если надо работать с текстовыми данными построчно...

Comment: На самом деле, вопрос в том, что вы подразумеваете под _читать_. При помощи streams часто легче обрабатывать данные, идущие потоком, это да. Но возникает вопрос о том, что же вы именно хотите сделать. Чтение данных из URL скорее всего не является потоковой операцией: большая часть работы — это открытие сетевого соединения обработка HTTP-сообщений (это всё обычно скрыто от вас библиотеками).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Окей, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вы хотите читать текст из URL построчно, получив stream на список строк. (То есть, аналог кода `BufferedReader input = ...; while( (line == input.readline()) != null) ...`.)

Это делается так (код одолжен в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691231/276994)):

```
try (InputStream is = new URL("http://www.nkode.io/assets/programming/countmychars.txt")
        .openConnection().getInputStream();
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     Stream<String> stream = reader.lines()) {
    // вот здесь у вас есть stream строк, делайте с ним что угодно
    // например:
    long maxLineLength = stream.mapToLong(e -> e.length()).max().getAsLong();
    System.out.println(maxLineLength);
}
```